# A query to ms-application-insights is returning results not consistent with a PowerBI query

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

A query call to https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/ returns counts but values are far less than a similar call to Power BI.

query

```
query=dependencies | where timestamp >= ago(48h) and type == 'Connection' and
name == 'Mediate' | summarize typeCount=count() by data | order by typeCount desc
```

The C# code is based on the Microsoft Provided sample.

There are no errors, it appears that the sample set is far smaller, so the results in descending order have counts starting in the 10's of thousands, rather than millions.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue was actually in my Power BI query.
I apologize for the post.